# What is the app's top bar called & how change its color?

Tags: java, android, flutter

1. What is the app's top bar called? An appbar? (I cicled it in the picture)
2. How can I change its color in Flutter by Android Studio?

[image: App top bar example]

Comment: no this is not an appbar this something else i don't what is called

Comment: You can make custom one

Comment: It is toolbar maybe

Comment: i don't think so .because toolbar is different from this .

Comment: Nomenclature of mobile app visual elements can be found here: https://uxdesign.cc/nomenclature-of-mobile-app-visual-elements-android-vs-ios-93685e8ef085.